# Google Chrome Omnibox Smart Answers

Tags: google-chrome

With the new version of Google Chrome that was released today (v69.0.3497.81), the Omnibox is supposed to give smart answers for certain queries. I've tried a few things that are based on the GIF they showed but it never works for me.

Has anyone had any luck with this working? Is it something that isn't fully working and maybe wasn't released yet? Is there a setting or flag that needs to be toggled? I haven't really found any solid answer.

[image]

Comment: I would disable all add-ons, verify autocomplete is otherwise working, since the feature is connected to it and then edit your question.

Comment: I had the [prediction service setting](https://i.imgur.com/Xkp2tJ9.png) toggled off. Turning it on solved the problem.

Comment: You should submit a proper answer.  I was simply guessing about the autocomplete, while I knew t was connected, was going to suggest you enable it unless you confirmed it was off :-)

Comment: @Ramhound if you don’t want to submit one I will. I was going to give you the honor since you had the right comment.

Comment: My research indicated that "autocomplete" is a pain disable.  Since prediction services, wasn't specifically "autocomplete", seems far you submit your own answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the Smart Answer predictions to work correctly, you need to make sure that the prediction service setting for searches and URLs is turned on.[image: prediction service setting]